# Function will not work return correct value with IF, ELSE Statement

Tags: python-2.7, function

['10.1.1.1', 'Bad IP address']

```
def findIP(IP):
    with open(tsvfile,'rt' )as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
            for row in reader:
                if IP.strip() in row[0]:
                    x = row[1]
                else:
                    x = "Activity Unknown"
                return x
```

The code works if I remove the else statement, but returns only "Activity Unknown" when else statement is present. I've tried a few different ways to make this work. They have all yielded same result.

```
return row[1] if IP.strip() in row[0] else "Activity Unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

1.when reader = [] you'll not enter for loop.

2.You have incorrect tabulated function:

```
def findIP(IP):
    with open(tsvfile,'rt' )as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            if IP.strip() in row[0]:
                x = row[1]
            else:
                x = "Activity Unknown"
            return x
```

3.You can write it shorter:

```
def findIP(IP):
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    try:
        return reader[0][1] if IP.strip() in reader[0][1] else "Activity Unknown"
    except IndexError:
        return "Activity Unknown"
```